# detect cms from list

Tags: scripting, programming, wordpress

my marketing department wanted from me detect our domains for that if they use Wordpress. I have our huge list of domains, but I can't find proper cms detector which will just save which domain has wordpress into output file.

I would be very thankful for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check website index page and grep for "WordPress" or better "wp-content" sub-string.

For example, I check few websites for "wp-content/themes" sub-string, one liner:

```
DOMAINS="enjoyyourcooking.com yabloko.studio academyselfdefense.com cnn.com middlechildphilly.com"; for i in ${DOMAINS}; do wget --timeout=5 -qO- ${i}|grep 'wp-content/themes' >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "+++ Domain ${i}: wordpress detected" || echo "--- Domain ${i}: wordpress NOT detected"; done
```

Output:

```
+++ Domain enjoyyourcooking.com: wordpress detected
+++ Domain yabloko.studio: wordpress detected
+++ Domain academyselfdefense.com: wordpress detected
--- Domain cnn.com: wordpress NOT detected
+++ Domain middlechildphilly.com: wordpress detected
```

Readable code version:

```
DOMAINS="enjoyyourcooking.com yabloko.studio academyselfdefense.com cnn.com middlechildphilly.com";
for i in ${DOMAINS}; do
  wget --timeout=5 -qO- ${i}|grep 'wp-content/themes' >/dev/null 2>&1 && 
    echo "+++ Domain ${i}: wordpress detected" || 
    echo "--- Domain ${i}: wordpress NOT detected";
done
```

Of course there is no warranty that searched sub-strings was not changed, when wordpress was modified for a particular website... but I cannot help with it.

Comment: thanks for this..and how to add list which is in file? Can I simply do DOMAINS="cat list.txt" ?

Comment: Instead defining a variable DOMAINS, you can simply read data directly from a file `... for i in $(cat list.txt); do ...`

Comment: or yes, you can do `DOMAINS="$(cat list.txt|xargs)"` (at the end `|xargs` added to make content of the variable one long string without new lines, it works without it too, but if you do more operations with variable - it may cause unexpected behavior)

Comment: I just little "upgraged it" with output to files. Thanks for help.

`DOMAINS="$(cat domains.txt|xargs)"
for i in ${DOMAINS}; do
  wget --timeout=5 -qO- ${i}|grep 'wp-content/themes' >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    echo "+++ Domain ${i}: wordpress detected" >> detected.txt ||
    echo "--- Domain ${i}: wordpress NOT detected" >> undetected.txt;
done `

Comment: in you line it looks like you missed `;` before `for`.